# Максимальный размер файла *.ibd в MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, windows-10, mysql-workbench

Подскажите как изменить ограничение на максимальный размер файла таблицы innodb. При достижении размера файла в 4 Гб выпадает исключение "The table 'buffer' is full". И после перезапуска сервера он начинает глючить (Показывает что запущен а при обращении вылетает)

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:917)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1246)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1241)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4102)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4071)
at com.tetra.lib.io.db.DataBaseORM.insert(DataBaseORM.java:131)
at com.tetra.lib.io.internet.TaskSend.insert(TaskSend.java:253)
at com.tetra.lib.io.internet.TaskSend.run(TaskSend.java:110)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 220 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 212 milliseconds ago.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at      com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:988)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3552)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3452)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3893)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:839)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:739)
at com.tetra.lib.io.db.buffer.MySQLJDBC.createTable(MySQLJDBC.java:71)
at com.tetra.lib.io.db.buffer.MySQLJDBC.<init>(MySQLJDBC.java:64)
at com.tetra.lib.io.db.DataBaseORM.createConnection(DataBaseORM.java:51)
at com.tetra.lib.io.db.DataBaseORM.<init>(DataBaseORM.java:38)
at com.tetra.lib.io.internet.AtlantRunnable.<init>(AtlantRunnable.java:53)
at ua.tetra.atlant.monitor.controller.MainController.atlant(MainController.java:283)
at ua.tetra.atlant.monitor.controller.MainController.<init>(MainController.java:94)
at ua.tetra.atlant.monitor.tetra_atlant_monitor.main(tetra_atlant_monitor.java:79)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:101)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:144)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:174)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3001)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3462)
... 16 more
```

Пробовал изменять настройки

```
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_log_buffer_size=200M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
```

При установке больших значений сервер просто не запускается "Время ожидания истекло"

Сейчас работаю с базой c помощью Java, JDBC.
Пытался залить в пустую базу дамп сделаный в macOS где-то 10 Гб та же ошибка "The table 'buffer' is full"

Windows 10 32 разрядная.

ОЗУ 3,25 Гб.
mysql 5.7.15.

Посмотрел лог файл исключение выпадает не на все insert.

```
2016-09-26T03:11:31.077085Z 11 [ERROR] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: The table 'buffer' is full
2016-09-26T03:25:29.966517Z 11 [ERROR] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: The table 'buffer' is full
2016-09-26T03:30:58.179531Z 11 [ERROR] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: The table 'buffer' is full
2016-09-26T03:36:30.177381Z 11 [ERROR] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: The table 'buffer' is full
2016-09-26T03:46:16.193598Z 11 [ERROR] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: The table 'buffer' is full
```

Comment: Переключайте таблицы c innodb в myisam и будет вторая жизнь.

Comment: Ваша база совершенно случайно не лежит на разделе с FAT32?

Comment: У меня раздел NTFS

Comment: Свободного места на диске много? Ещё у вас может быть LOG переполнен, посмотрите [здесь](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/full-table.html) последний пост Stephen DeGabriele.

Comment: Свободного места около 50гиг, Установил innodb_log_file_size=900M innodb_log_buffer_size=200М, если установить больше сервер не запускается

Comment: Старый лог удаляли?

Comment: На виртуальной машине протестировал: Windows 7 64bit все хорошо; Windows 7 32 bit база 4 гига начались исключения, после рестарта сервера mysql он постоянно подключается; Windows 10 32 при базе в 4 гига теже бока, даже с измененными настройками

Comment: Интересная особенность на десятке программа писала 4 дня, сейчас сыпятся исключения таблица заполнена, но размер файла больше 10 гиг